# Can I use constants within functions in PHP?

Tags: php, constants

Is it possible to use a PHP constant within a PHP function?

```
// in a different file
DEFINE ('HOST', 'hostname');
DEFINE ('USER', 'username');
DEFINE ('PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('NAME', 'dbname');

// connecting to database
function database()
{
    // using 'global' to define what variables to allow
    global $connection, HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME;
    $connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME)
        or die ('Sorry, Cannot Connect');
    return $connection;
}
```

Comment: improving phrasing skills is something and discouraging is something entirely different. don't be a troll

Comment: Agree with @HerrK, the downvotes are highly discouraging and unnecessary at times. Besides, YourCommonSense, you who are voicing for downvoting people for their phrasing skills, how should we downvote you for your phrasing skill in "but he need to improve" ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to declare them in `global` in the function, PHP recognises them as globals.

```
function database()
{
  // using 'global' to define what variables to allow
  global $dbc;
  $connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, NAME)
      or die ('Sorry, Cannot Connect');
  return $connection;
}
```

From php.net:

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope. For more information on scope, read the manual section on [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Just upvoted your answer but would like to point out that *the php recognise them as superglobals.* should be *the php recognise them as globals.*

Answer (score 4):

Have you at least tried it? :)

From the [manual](http://php.net/constants):

> Like superglobals, the scope of a
>   constant is global. You can access
>   constants anywhere in your script
>   without regard to scope.

Answer (score 3):

`define()` produces global constants.

[There are much better ways to store config items.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593440/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-configuration-variables-in-php)

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is any clear conclusion that those are that much better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you don't need to call them "global". Constants are global. If you get `unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE` as an error, it's because it doesn't expect to see the constant references after a "global" statement.