# Where to keep settings of displaying web page? (php/xml/json/ini)

Tags: php, templates, configuration-files

I have a little Templating class, that keeps all settings inside the php class.

These settings are: css styles, js scripts, meta tags and titles for every page. (For example on index.php I need some js-scripts, but for contacts.php - other js-files).

It's not very comfortable to edit this configuration data, because it is in private properties of a class, and while editing programmer can make mistakes in php code).

Is it a good idea to keep this configuration data in external files? Xml/json/ini ?
Will this get site rendering much slower?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593440/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-configuration-variables-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using.ini files is great feature in PHP:

```
class Template {
    private $config;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = parse_ini_file('templates.ini');
    }
    public function fetch() {
        $this->config['default_dir']; // example
    }
}
```

- Documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

---

According to your comment - loading it's not that fast. But you can always cache .ini files in memory:

```
class IniFiles {
    private static $_files = Array();
    public static function parse($file) {
        if(isset(self::$_files[$file])) return self::$_files[$file];
        self::$_files[$file] = parse_ini_file($file);
        return self::$_files[$file];
    }
}

class Template {
    private $config;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->config = IniFiles::parse('templates.ini');
    }
    public function fetch() {
        $this->config['default_dir']; // example
    }
}
```

Now it's perfect solution. :)

Comment: So, it's pretty fast, isn't it?

Comment: @Innuendo Don't worry about speed until that's a problem.  It usually is not a concern.

Comment: It's problematic if you use many of templates. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Why do you use a class with a static function when a global function with a static variable inside would do the same?

Comment: @hakre: It's just looks nicer to me. And maybe one day you would like to put more features to class :) Errors, loading times, debugging etc.

Comment: More features into global static class functions with global static class variables? No, you won't want to do that.

Comment: For example Zend_Loader do that. And there is nothing wrong about it. (loading .php files, not .ini but idea is same)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it a good idea to keep this configuration data in external files?

Yes that's a good idea, normally those are called configuration files.

> Xml/json/ini?

Choose whatever suits your needs and preference.

> Will this get site rendering much slower?

No rendering is not related to it, the rendering code will not be changed.

Comment: I understand that rendering won't be changed, and it's not related. by `rendering` I've meant the whole process of displaying web-page. Early configs were got from private variable, but now - it will be read from config-file ( ini/json/xml ), that should be parsed at first. So, it requires more time to get these configs.

Comment: The basic rule is: The more you do, the longer it takes. Reading files takes relatively long, but I would trade the (little) speed drawback for having a configuration file against the speed drawback you get by introducing errors when you edit the code because of configuration. You can combine both with a build system that encodes the configuration together with the code for production.

Comment: Ok, so we'll always need to sacrifice of something

Comment: Exactly. If confiugration files help you to keep your code modular, go for it. I don't know your code, maybe having a `TemplateConfiguration` type is a good idea here, so you can have templates independent to the concrete configuration. On the other hand, your Template class might benefit from a better design, so to get responsibilities for linked resources completely out of it because it's not it's business at all but just being a template, not a link/resource manager.